# How can I avoid losing KeepNext from ParagraphProperties when adding a new Run to a paragraph in a table?

Tags: openxml

I am iterating through paragraphs, swapping out text by replacing Runs with new Runs. I have a table with KeepNext on all its paragraphs. When I replace a Run in a Paragraph in the table with a clone with new text in it, I lose the KeepNext formatting from the ParagraphProperties.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Paragrah.InsertAfter to add my new cloned Run to the Paragraph - even when there was no Run to insert after... In those cases I simply passed null as the refChild param in InsertAfter(). This made the Paragraph lose formatting, but that seems to be the only ill effect as I only had issues when KeepNext disappeared from my Paragraphs.

Using Paragraph.Append in these cases fixed the issue, but in some cases I still needed to insert the new Run at the start of the paragraph. In those cases, inserting the new Run as the first of the ChildElements made the KeepNext formatting disappear. Take care to add the Run after the ParagraphProperties element, if it is present, to maintain the KeepNext formatting.